# Why the phase space of $(\dot x,\dot y)=(y,-\sin(x))$ is a cylinder?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system

$$\begin{cases}\dot x=y\\ \dot y=-\sin(x).\end{cases}$$

Why the phase space is a cylinder ? By the way, the phase space isn't the graph of $(\dot x,\dot y)=(y,-\sin(x))$ in the coordinate $(x,\dot x, y,\dot y)$ ? (as it is for example for the pendulum in $(\theta ,\dot \theta )$).

Comment: Because $y^2-2\cos x$ is constant along each solution.

Comment: @Did: Thank you, but I don't really understand why it gives a cylinder... could elaborate a bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the system is invariant if you change $x$ by $2\pi$. If you go with the physical interpretation as pendulum equation, then $x$ is the angle, the physical point is $(L\cos x, L\sin x)$ and you can interpret the phase space as the cylinder $(\cos x, \sin x, \dot x)\in\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you (you look to be a OD specialist :)). For the phase portrait of the pendulum why is $(\theta ,\dot \theta )$ and here is also in 2D, shouldn't it be $(x,\dot x,y,\dot y)$ ?

Comment: You can do that. Then you get the physical system \begin{align}\ddot x&=\lambda x\\\ddot y &=-g + \lambda y\\L^2&=x^2+y^2\end{align} which is an index-3 DAE system.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the periodic stream plot

[image]

Here in red is represented a center and in blue a saddle point.

Now gluing the vertical sides ...

[image]

Follows the MATHEMATICA script used

`gr1 = StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   StreamStyle -> {Black, Fine}];
pt1 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.08]}];
pt2 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{-Pi, 0}, 0.08]}];
pt3 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{Pi, 0}, 0.08]}];
Show[gr1, pt1, pt2, pt3]`

and

`gr2 = Graphics3D[(Normal@gr1)[[1]] /. a_Arrow :> (a /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {Cos[x], Sin[x], y})];
pt1 = Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 0.08]}];
pt2 = Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[{-1, 0, 0}, 0.08]}];
Show[gr2, pt1, pt2]`

Comment: the pendulum oscillate on a cylinder ?

Comment: @NewMath No. It's phase variety can be represented as a cylinder without ambiguity.

Comment: @Cesareo: What did you use to draw the second figure?

Comment: @Moo Please. See note attached.